# Div class showing up as random string instead of name in google chrome web inspector

Tags: web-scraping, web-inspector

I'm trying to follow an intro tutorial on web scraping (https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/07/web-scraping-in-python-using-scrapy/) and it is working with the game of thrones reddit page https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/. In the tutorial, it says when you inspect the title of a post, it will show as "

```
<div class = "top matter"> 
<p class = "title">
```

etc. But when I inspect the title, it shows as

```
<a data-click-id="body" class="SQnoC3ObvgnGjWt90zD9Z" href="/r/gameofthrones/comments/bwc0te/no_spoilers_justgiving_fundraiser_for_kit/"><h2 class="yk4f6w-0 lbhQOA">[NO SPOILERS] JustGiving fundraiser for Kit Harington's charity Mencap</h2></a>
<h2 class="yk4f6w-0 lbhQOA">[NO SPOILERS] JustGiving fundraiser for Kit Harington's charity Mencap</h2>
```

or for example when I try to inspect the vote count:

```
 <div class="s1h1p2hu-0 fIbDHO"><button class="_2k73nZrjAYiwAj9hv7K-kq" theme="[object Object]" aria-label="upvote" aria-pressed="false" data-click-id="upvote" id="upvote-button-t3_bwc0te" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://styles.redditmedia.com/t5_2rjz2/styles/postUpvoteIconInactive_6fsa07qaj5t01.png&quot;); width: 24px; height: 24px;"></button><div class="_1rZYMD_4xY3gRcSS3p8ODO" style="color: rgb(26, 26, 27);">412</div><button class="ceU_3ot04pOVIcrrXH9fY" theme="[object Object]" aria-label="downvote" aria-pressed="false" data-click-id="downvote" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://styles.redditmedia.com/t5_2rjz2/styles/postDownvoteIconInactive_a6hsvdx3j5t01.png&quot;); width: 24px; height: 24px;"></button></div>
```

I've tried to open the page in FireFox as well and the same issue occurs. So I know it's not adblock.

I've tried another page like Ebay and the titles of div classes/ids are slightly more descriptive, so I'm not sure what's happening.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The HTML markup of the page has changed in the 2 years since the tutorial was first published.

If you want to follow along using the original markup from 2017, you could use the page from Wayback Machine at:  https://web.archive.org/web/20170725035139/https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/

The screenshot below shows the expected markup as explained in the tutorial:

[image]